# C#: what part of my code needs .net framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, frameworks

My situation is the following: I start a new projekt in my visual studio 2022 and choose the .net framework 2.0 as the target framework. And just if i write a simple console programm with Console.WriteLine("Hello World");: My problem is, if i start this program at a fresh installed windows 10 21h2, then i get a message that i have to install .net 3.5. (the 2.0 and 3.0 would be there).

How can i figure out, which part of my code needs .net.3.5 although i choose .net 2.0 at beginning of my project?

Comment: I think it's the other way round. You can't have .net2 installed **without** having .net3.5 installed. Therefor I suppose it's that your maschine simply has only 4.x installed. Anyway: why do you even chose such an old framework at all? .net2 is 20 years old...

Comment: Net versions before 4.3 required all older versions of Net to be installed.  Each net library only contained the incremental changes from previous versions.  So to run an app you needed to install Net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5.  Starting with Net 4.3 all the methods were in the one version of Net.

Comment: All supported versions of Windows now come with at least .Net 4.8, so I guess you should be targeting that rather than .NET 2.0 which came out in 2005 (and which I hope you're not confusing with .NET Standard 2.0)

Comment: Yes, its a very old framework but the program must run on older systems, connected to machines in industry. they are not well patched, because manufacturer avoids to change something on complex, running systems. so they dont have .net framework 3.5 installed. and my idea was to go back to the lowest or first .net framework i can choose and in the application options, i can choose as target framework .net framework 2.0 or 3.0 or 3.5 and so on-i mean the ".net framework " and not the ".net". and my thoughts behind were:if i choose the .net framework 2.0: there is just required the 2.0,you know?